# Select multiple children of a class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have a div full of button tags

```js
$('#class_selector button').click(function(a){
    $('#class_selector').hide();
    console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="class_selector">
<button>Click</button>
<button>Click</button>
<button>Click</button>
</div>
```

This just simply doesn't work. I want to assign an action to every button of a "selector" class to hide the selector div itself after being clicked on - this is how I'd select it with CSS and I thought it'd work but it doesn't. buttons don't get any JS events

Comment: div is hiding for me

Comment: it works even on stackoverflow snippet... is the content of selector generated dynamically?

Comment: *"This just simply doesn't work...buttons don't get any JS events"* Yes, they do. Clicking any of your buttons above hides the div. (It takes a second because the `console.log(a)` takes a long time with the in-snippet console.)

Comment: Stackoverflow snippet lags the browser very much but yeah somehow it works here. Content is static - nothing is generated. Just in case: Firefox 62.0.2 JQuery 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understood, you want every button with a specific class to hide a div on click. You can do that by assigning an *on-click* event handler to any button that has that said class in its class list.

**HTML**

```
<div id="selector-buttons">
  <button class="selector-button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="selector-button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="selector-button">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
// grab everything that has the 'selector-button' class in its class list
$('.selector-button').on('click', ()=>{
    // hide the div
        $('#selector-buttons').hide();
    });
});
```

Check out this [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/xpvt214o/840921/) for a working example

On the other hand, if you don't want to assign a class you can do it like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="selectors">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
        // get every button inside the div
        $('#selectors').find('button').on('click', ()=>{
        // hide the div
        $('#selectors').hide();
    });
})
```

Here's a [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/RaysOfTheSun/3nmfoevx/20/) for a working example.

Comment: That would be a workaraound for now but assigning every button with a class is tiresome and it would make a file weight more than it should so instead of assiginin a class to every single button I've decided to to select every button in a classed div like ".div_name button" instead of ".class_for_all_buttons"
This workaround makes sense, unlinke the other choice which should work but doesn't.

Firefox 62.0.2
JQuery 3.3.1
Just in case

Comment: Any chance "position: absolute;" prevents the parent div from disappearing?

Comment: I've updated my answer :) Nah. I believe jquery uses the "display" property to make the element disappear

Comment: Nevermind, I've assigned "click" events before the buttons existed. Such a silly mistake. Thanks though!